# contentbuilder.js keep toolbar visible at all times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im currently working with the contentbuilder.js script to prepare a simple page to allow content editing.

Whilst I love this particular script, I havent been able to find a way to keep the toolbar visible at all times. The readme file doesnt give out too much information, but im wondering if anyone has worked with this before and managed to keep the toolbar visible at all times, but when the text isnt in focus, make the buttons disabled.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hey I used the following on my page to make it show up as long as the builder had focus

```
$("#<%=contentarea.ClientID%>").mousedown(function(event) {
                    jQuery("#rte-toolbar").stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
                });
```